# Loading the dataset everytime when kernel starts?

Tags: python-2.7, kernel, jupyter-notebook

Do I need to load dataset everytime I shut down the kernel and start again the next day?
As I am constantly getting an error of NameError that the train dataset has not been identified.

Is there any better way rather than to load dataset and run the same commands again?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to try. You could create and load a pickle object. I've done this for large text based datasets.

Have a look at the  %%cache magic at https://github.com/rossant/ipycache

This can be used to save your data in a pickle like object between sessions.

Search stackoverflow for 'how to cache jpython notebook'.

I'd have added this just as a comment as I am not supplying code examples, but I don't have the necessary reputation.